# Does windows workflow 3 have a concept of working days?

Tags: workflow-foundation

I'm looking at the possibility of using Windows Workflow 3.0 (or possibly version 4) for a future project. I've done a fair amount of spec/tutorial/white-paper reading but I can't seem to find any information on implementing a workflow that understands working week days/public holidays etc. These concepts are very common in live systems so maybe I'm just looking in all the wrong places.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Have I missed something, is this something that WWF can handle out of the box? - if so any pointers appreciated.
2. Is it just a case of setting the timeout on a delay activity dynamically based on my own logic in a previous stage of the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

So you want have the workflow act on certain dates that are work week days/public holidays etc.? You're correct in that WF doesn't support this out of the box. 
I'd go with option #2.

Also if you're interested in WF4 Ron Jacobs has a sample on [how to make a batch like workflow service that'll delay executing](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Workflow-Services-as-a-Batch-Job).